# Best way to layout application?

Tags: backbone.js, view, marionette

**Edit:** Fixed JSFiddle Link

So i've been playing with Backbone and Marionette since a couple of weeks. I did some courses on Udemy, read the docs for both Backbone and Marionette. I can grasp most of the logic but somehow my mind can't wrap itself around the best way to approach a SPA I am trying to create.

## API

So I have a rest api that returns some data:

`http://localhost:3000/index`

returns the following:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "magazineTitle": "Title",
        "magazineEditie": "Date",
        "indexTitle": "Index Title",
        "indexSubtitle": "Index Subtitle",
        "mediaType": "image", //can also be "video"
        "mainMedia": "https://source.unsplash.com/B0iF3I4bLBQ"
    }
]
```

## What I want

I want to be able to use this response and populate it over 2 seperate views.

- one view will use the data to create a navigation bar
- the other view will use it to create a hero header

## What I can't seem to understand

Somehow I can't wrap my head around how this would be set up without making this 'illogical'

I feel like loading 2 views with the same model inside my `Marionette.Application` doesn't make any sense? Or the fact that I fetch my Collections and/or Models there...

I need some help clearing up some Layout issues and best practices I guess.

## My code

Besides the fact that I get the data from a localhost url and I have my app setup with webpack this is more or less the code that I am using:

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lmr093nL/16/)

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out what I needed to do. Based on the documentation (which was kind of confusing me) I figured out a way to render two views with it's needed data.

I was using a CollectionView to read a single data point (1 model) I somehow couldn't figure out a way to immediately get a single Model.

So far the model I had to do:

## index.model.js

```
const IndexModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: "http://localhost:3000/index",
    default: {
        id: 1,
        magazineTitle: "Mag Title",
        magazineEditie: "Date",
        indexTitle: "Title",
        indexSubtitle: "Subtitle",
        mediaType: "image",
        mainMedia: "http://placehold.it/1900x800/",
    },
});
```

The urlRoot argument here is what I need to do the exact call.

Then I was still confused how to structure my app but I ultimately used `Regions` and `Marionette.View` to setup the application.

## App.js

```
export default Marionette.Application.extend({
    region: "#content",

    onBeforeStart() {
        const router = new Router();
    },

    onStart() {
        this.showView(new AppView());
    },
});
```

## app.view.js

```
const AppView = Marionette.View.extend({
    tagName: "main",
    id: "app",
    template: template,
    regions: {
        navigationRegion: "#main-navigation",
        appRegion: "#main-region",
        pagesRegion: "#pages-region",
    },

    initialize() {
        this.headerData = new IndexModel({ id: 1 });
        this.pagesData = new PagesCollection();
    },

    onRender() {
        this.showChildView("appRegion", new HeroView({ model: this.headerData, }));
        this.showChildView("pagesRegion", new PagesView({ collection: this.pagesData, }));
    },
});
```

I had to create a wrapping `AppView` that utilises regions to specify where child views should render.